# Problem with Intel video acceleration on Debian Stretch

Tags: debian, intel, vaapi

On my Lenovo Ideapad S110 Debian Stretch is just working fine, but HD videos don't run smoothly, at least not in full screen.

i965-va-driver is installed and up to date, vainfo returns

```
    sudo vainfo
    error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
    libva info: VA-API version 0.39.4
    libva info: va_getDriverName() returns -1
    libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null)
    vaInitialize failed with error code -1 (unknown libva error),exit
```

Maybe anybody can help. Thanks!

Comment: All HD videos? And are they local files or from streaming? Codecs, etc.?

Answer (score 3):

Your [laptop](https://support.lenovo.com/fr/en/solutions/pd023081) has a [GMA 3150](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_GMA#GMA_3150) integrated GPU, which isn’t supported by the `i965` VA-API driver. I’m not aware of any way to get it working better; it’s rather under-powered for full-screen HD video... The hardware only supports [MPEG-2 acceleration](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Intel-Graphics-Media-Accelerator-3150.23264.0.html), not H.264 acceleration, which is what you’d typically need for HD video.